# Why R plots Residuals vs Leverage instead of Residuals vs Factor Levels (ANOVA test & model with 'aov')

Tags: r, anova

I'm analysing a data set with the weight of newborn babies and some info about their mothers, including a categorical variable 'smoke' - whether a mother is a smoker, or not.

I did an aov test and wanted to plot diagnostic plots of an ANOVA model with its help. I expected to get four plots, including a 'Residuals vs Factor Levels' plot. Instead, I got a 'Residuals vs Leverage' plot, as if my categorical variable was a numeric one.

You can find the dataset here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VwiAHdYZF2BrGZZ875GGdkyamKMgxmGU/view?usp=sharing

In there variable 'smoke' has values 0 (non-smoker) and 1 (smoker). I used mutate to change it into a proper factor (among others, like parity), then made the aov test itself and tried to plot the results, to verify the assumptions. Below you can find my code:

```
babies <- read.csv("babies.csv")
babies <- babies %>% 
mutate(parity = factor(parity, 
                     levels = c(0, 1), 
                     labels = c("not firstborn", "firstborn"))) %>% 
mutate(smoke = factor(smoke, 
                    levels = c(0, 1), 
                    labels = c("non smoker", "smoker")))

model6 <- aov(babies$bwt ~ babies$smoke)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(aov(babies$bwt ~ babies$smoke))
```

The result I'm getting in the fourth plot is this:

[image]

I tried to check whether 'smoke' is a factor as I wanted or not, like that:

```
> head(babies$smoke)
[1] non smoker non smoker smoker     non smoker smoker     non smoker
Levels: non smoker smoker
```

Since 'smoke' is a factor (as I understand) and a categorical variable, why is there leverage as per numeric variable? How to fix this and get the proper plot?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `plot.aov` method, so you got the `plot.lm` method (since the class of `aov(babies$bwt ~ babies$smoke)` would be `c("aov", "lm")`).

If you want to plot something else for `"aov"` objects, write a function `plot.aov` to do it.  For example,

```
plot.aov <- function(x, which = 1:3, ...) {
  NextMethod(x, which = which, ...)
  for (f in names(x$xlevels)) {
    xvar <- x$model[, f]
    plot(xvar, residuals(x), xlab = f, ylab = "Residuals")
  }
}
```

Then

```
plot(aov(babies$bwt ~ babies$smoke))
```

will plot the first 3 `plot.lm` plots, followed by residual plots against the factor in your model.  (It will do each of the factors if there are others.)  I get

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, you can use the `termplot` function, e.g.

```
termplot(aov(babies$bwt ~ babies$smoke), partial.resid=TRUE)
```

which gives this plot:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this proposition. It seems to have a wide range of applications in general, so think I'll use it. I'm still wondering tough, how to get a generic plot as presented in here (page 6): https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/bwebb/statistics/ANOVA_in_R.pdf - any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know.  When I run the code from those notes I get the residuals versus level plot just like the notes, but not on your data....

Comment: Okay, from looking at the code:  you'll get that plot only if there is constant leverage, which would happen (only?) with equal numbers of each group.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I made a test set of some data of two categories with the same number of observations in both of the categories. This last plot worked, meaning it was a plot of residuals vs factor levels. Thank you very much!